# Calculate the dimension of $K$-vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, groebner-basis

> **Problem:** Let monomial ideal $I = \langle x^3,y^3 \rangle \subseteq K[x,y]$, consider quotient ring $V = K[x,y]/I$ as a $K$-vector space. Calculate the dimension of $K$-vector space $V$.

Could you give me some hint to solve this problem. Thank all!

Comment: What is $I$?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If $I=K[x,y]$, then $V$ is the trivial vector space!

Comment: Which is so trivial, I thought it must be a typo.

Comment: @Minh Nguyễn Hoàng: Do you really mean $I=K[x,y]$? If so, Arturo Magidin's comment yields an instant answer.

Comment: Sorry all! I'm going edit.

Comment: **Not** equal to $K[x,y]$.

Comment: Every element of $K[x,y]$ is a sum of monomials. Which monomials are congruent to zero modulo $I$? What does that leave?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, you have edited it. $I \subseteq K[x,y]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You meant $\dim(V) = \dim K[x,y]$?

Comment: I can’t imagine where you think I might have meant that. So... no.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So, what did you meant?

Comment: I meant what I said; to check what monomials are congruent to zero modulo $I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the dimension is the number of standard monomials in the quotient ring, here $1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2,x^2y,xy^2,x^2y^2$ taken modulo $I$.

Comment: What does “taken modulo I” meant?

Comment: You work in the quotient ring.

Comment: So $\dim(V)=9$?

Comment: You‘re right, dimension nine